# OMXplayer won't start after some period of work

Tags: video, omxplayer

i use raspberry pi 2, with raspbian jessie and omxplayer build date "23.sept2016",
... for playing livestream that is not perfect. OMXplayer stops after while, but i use it in endless loop loop so it restarts itself.

BUT after some period, sometimes one hour, sometimes 5 minutes, ... omxplayer get in some state that i can not run it anymore. Only system reboot helps.

in that state, i am testing simple playing offline mp4 and nothing happens.

`omxplayer somefile.mp4` do not show any errors just hangs, and stops only after ctrl+c.

`omxplayer -g somefile.mp4` creates omxplayer.log with only one line: "DllBcm: Using omx system library"

i also tried lsof of libraries while omxplayer 'running doing nothing', and inside /opt/vc/lib/* this 8 libraries are used by omxplayer: bcm_host, EGL, GLESv1_CM, GLESv2, openmaxil, chiq_arm, vcos, WFC... which is normal because i reboot computer, start omxplayer again and same number of libraries are used by working omxplayer.

So -g *generate debug file" did not help me at all. Does anyone have some idea how to DEBUG this state.

It is maybe "state of system, not just omxplayer" some resource blocked...

Answer (score 0):

radical approach DID NOT solved my problem

```
- using new sd-card
- using new operating system (archlinux arm instead of raspbian)
- using tmpfs (ram-memory mounts) for /run, /tmp, /var/log, /var/tmp, /var/spoold/mqueue
- removing '--live' from omxplayer parameters (seems more stable without it)
```

seems that either omxplayer logging was bad, or whole raspberry pi decision to use SD Card as main disk produces hard to track errors.